# How to switch back to the Main view i.e ViewController.h" what is the nib name for MainStoryboard.storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I use the following code to switch from main view (`ViewController.h`)to another view (`TouchViewController`) and then similarly switch from this view to the next view (`QuestionsViewController`).
**How do I go back to the main view from here?** i.e what is the value for `initWithNibName` for `MainStoryboard.storyboard`?

```
- (IBAction)startGame:(UIButton *)sender {

    TouchViewController *second = [[TouchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TouchViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and

```
- (IBAction)selectTopic:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *category = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:category forKey:@"MyKey"];
    QuestionsViewController *second = [[QuestionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuestionsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now to go back to the main view i have a problem i.e

```
- (IBAction)backtoMainMenu:(id)sender {
    ViewController *second = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainStoryboard.storyboard" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

At this point the app just crashes! I suppose it's because `initWithNibName:@"MainStoryboard.storyboard"` can't be used but the `ViewController` does not have any other `xib` file - so what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

First of all `storyboard` can't be used as a xib file they are not the same thing. Second you have one view controller that presents  a view controller that also present a view controller so what you can do is something like this from the third view controller:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController 
            void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is the fastest way you can do it, but it's not really reusable, if you have a more complex view controller hierarchy than it will be really ugly to do it like this, other solutions can be delgates or notifications.

Also just a piece of advice, when you want to go back to a previous screen in general you don't what to create a new view controller (as you try in `backToMainMenu` method, you simply want to remove all the view controllers (screens) until you reach the desired screen.